# Inetgrating custom Fxcop rule with existing Fxcop rule

Tags: c#, code-analysis, fxcop

I have developed some Fxcop  custom rule and I want to create seperate project just like 'Design Rules','Globalization Rules' etc which will contain custom rule which was designed by me and some selected existing Miscrosoft Fxcop Rules. I want to know whether it is possible to do so. If possible ,How ?

Comment: What do you mean by a "project"?  A `.ruleset` file or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to place the `custom rule dll-file` in your correct FxCop-rulelocation:

This can be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop\Rules` for example. Find your location and place it in there.

What you want to do next is create a `Code Analysis Ruleset`.

There is a Microsoft tutorial on creating Code Analysis Rulesets [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264974.aspx).

> To open an empty rule set file in the rule set editor
>   On the File menu of Visual Studio, point to New and then click File.
>   In the New File dialog box, click General in the Installed Templates list, and then select Code Analysis Rule Set.
>   The rule set editor appears. No rules are selected in the editor list.

What you see next is the `Rule Set Editor`. Here you can select existing rules and also your own, custommade rules.

Working with the ruleset editor is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380626.aspx).

Comment: I followed the same process and VS doesn't give me any error while loading my  custom ruleset but I couldn't find my custom dll in Ruleset editor where all default Microsoft Rules('Design Rules','Globalization Rules' etc) are displayed with check box for enabling and disabling.

Comment: It appears there is something wrong with your custom rule then. Maybe open a new question for that?

Comment: @Matthijs: It's not actually necessary to put the rule assembly in the  `FxCop\Rules` folder.  If you wish to use an alternate location, this is possible, although it requires you to specify that location in the ruleset file via the `RuleHintPaths` element.

Comment: @NicoleCalinoiu you are correct, I should have included that option. Though to keep things simple in this case might be a good solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a step-by-step guide available at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/codeanalysis/archive/2010/03/26/how-to-write-custom-static-code-analysis-rules-and-integrate-them-into-visual-studio-2010.aspx for authoring rules and adding them to `.ruleset` files.  To figure out where the problem is originating, it would be best to follow all the recommended steps, including verifying that the rule can be executed by the `fxcopcmd.exe` command line tool.